# C++ concatenate two arrays without deep copying

Tags: c++, arrays, double

I have two arrays of each size 3 as:

```
void main() {
    double* arr1 = new double[3];
    double* arr2 = new double[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr1[i] = 0;
        arr2[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

And I have a function that takes a double array as pointer:

```
void func(double* arr_6D) {
   // expected arr size = 6.
   // manipulates values of arr
   for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      arr_6D[i] = 1;
   }
}
```

I want to pass in arr1 and arr2 together to the function so that their ***original*** values are manipulated by the function.

How can I do this?

Below wouldn't work since it's making a copy of the original arrays:

```
double *arr_merged = new double[6];
arr_merged[0] = arr1[0];
arr_merged[1] = arr1[1];
arr_merged[2] = arr1[2];
arr_merged[3] = arr2[0];
arr_merged[4] = arr2[1];
arr_merged[5] = arr2[2];
func(arr_merged);
```

Comment: why not using  `std::vector<double>` to be able to change size for instance to add new values and do your merge ?

Comment: Pass the arrays by reference and assign them to a new array by reference

Comment: You can't do it. If you could change the `func` signature to accept your custom type, you could write a `struct { double* first, double* second };` with overloaded `operator[]` to give the access to elements of both arrays without making a copy.

Comment: @bruno I didn't write some details, but the 'func(double * arr_6D) is from a library and fixed. I can't change it to for example, func(std::vector<double> &arr_6d)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Can you show me an example?

Comment: @pptaszni I didn't write some details, but the 'func(double * arr_6D) is from a library and fixed. I can't change it to for example, func(std::vector<double> &arr_6d)

Comment: `void func(double*& arr1, double*& arr2)`

Comment: @Joon.P you can use `std::vector<float>` and give underlying array to your function, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

you cannot modify the size of an array you create using `new double[<size>]`, to be able to do your merge so to modify the size use `std::vector<float>`, also offering a lot of additional behaviors

> 'func(double * arr_6D) is from a library and fixed. I can't change it to for example, func(std::vector &arr_6d)

you can get the underlying array serving as element storage using the operation `data()`

```
std::vector<double> arr1 = { ... }
...
std::vector<double> arr2 = { ... }
...
// concatenate arr1 with arr2
arr1.insert( arr1.end(), arr2.begin(), arr2.end() );
...
// call your func with underlying array
func(arr1.data());
```

warning to take care when manipulating the underlying array